# How to Display pdf file in blogger which is already stored in the server

Tags: pdf, iframe, blogger, pdfview

I want to show pdf url ( for example: http://www.newforests.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/sample_pdf.pdf) inside blogger without uploading in google docs.

If i upload the same pdf in google docs and if i give the embedded link in post html as

```
<iframe height="500" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A9jsNhASM9VmRra3J6WTZmZVU/edit?usp=sharing" width="750"></iframe>
```

I can able to see the pdf file in blogger. Its working fine. Likewise i want to show pdf file with defined server url in blogger without uploading pdf file in drive. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing  Google Drive pdf with your own pdf should work:

```
<iframe height="500" 
src="http://www.newforests.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/sample_pdf.pdf" 
width="750"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Appoorv, I tried this before but only i saw preview and pdf not loaded, Now i published the post and checked it. Its working fine. Thanks.